# No Such Host is knows

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dns, host

I'm trying to get the hostname from client IPAddress and it's always returns me the same error I have tried every possible solution on the internet Help me to find the solution for this.

```
"[ERROR] 050423 11:38:17.35, [16900_16]-Error while getting host name 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress address)"
```

Comment: Does a dns lookup work for that IP anywhere? You may try nslookup on a commandline.

Comment: @Ralf No it's giving error Non-existent domain

Comment: Is the DNS server presumably also mentioned in the nslookup response under your control?

Comment: yes it gives the response but giving error of non-existent domain. @Ralf

Comment: Then the DNS setup of that host has a problem and that needs to be fixed. There is nothing you can do if you don't have access to the DNS config for that host.